# Background music jquery sound

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been making an app.

It is now at the point were I need to start adding some background music.

I want to use jQuery to play it, and when it finishes replay it.

Here is the background music I want to use . http://picosong.com/2fR8/

And this is the code I have already tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(body).playSound('http://picosong.com/2fR8/');
});
```

And it does not work

Comment: `does not work` is not a proper problem statement. What errors are thrown?

Comment: Yep sorry about that, I mean that it does not play the propper sound.
EDIT: Or any sound at al

Comment: My apologies, here is the error in the console
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Sounds like you are missing whatever plugin file `playSound()` comes from, or it is loaded incorrectly, or path is wrong

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $audioElement = $("<audio>");
    $audioElement.attr({
        'src': 'http://picosong.com/media/songs/a53ac958428e20721ab0b5b2e3cf16c1.mp3',
        'autoplay':'autoplay',
        'loop':'loop'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're going to start with $(document).ready... you might as well as put everything in jquery.

Comment: For some reason it does not work when i put it in to a fiddle

Comment: $audioElement.get(0).play(); --- play() is not a jquery function (and the $ was forgotten)

Comment: @NicholasAyoub try it again seems that mp3 link didn't work anymore, changed it for another one

Comment: Im confused man, can you put it in a fiddle for me, it will not work. :/

Comment: sure [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crryntvj/4/) you should find another mp3 hosting, that one won't work for this, is changing the url every 2 min